# Packet gen dpdk file sending terminal command

Tags: dpdk

Is packetgen dpdk through its terminal able to send an already existing pcap file over a port? If is is able to send kindly provide a basic command structure example through which i can send the file over a port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DPDK PKTGEN can send pcap file content on a specific port. Please refer to the PKTGEN documentation for the option `-s P:file: The PCAP packet file to stream. P is the port number`.

link: https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_pktgen.html

using the option will in turn set

1. `Flags:Port      :   P---p----------:0   P---p----------:1` in `page main`.
2. command `page pcap` will open pcap related information page.
3. to selectively enable dpdk interface to send pcap use `enable|disable pcap`